# Переопредление equals и hashCode для проверки наличия объекта в Set

Tags: java, коллекции

У меня есть `Set` вида:

```
private Set<Row> selectedRows = new HashSet<>();
```

В определенный момент в нем лежит объект вида:

```
[Row [rowData={DFOBJ_ACC=105708976, DFNUMBER_ACC=229000032841, DFALIAS=Северо-Запад, FIRST_GROUP_DFOBJ=3180360969, FIRST_GROUP_NAME=Test 2 lines, SECOND_GROUP_DFOBJ=3180360970, SECOND_GROUP_NAME=Алиас, DFGROUP_NAME=, DFOBJ_CONTR=105708991, DFNUMBER_CONTR=№, от 09.07.2013, DFDATE_BEGIN=09.07.13, DFSUB_NUM=503, DFINVOICE=, DFBALANCE_OUT=0, null=T}]]
```

Мне нужно, когда приходит объект `Row` вида:

```
Row [rowData={DFOBJ_ACC=105708976, DFNUMBER_ACC=229000032841, DFALIAS=Северо-Запад, FIRST_GROUP_DFOBJ=3180360969, FIRST_GROUP_NAME=Test 2 lines, SECOND_GROUP_DFOBJ=3180360970, SECOND_GROUP_NAME=Алиас, DFGROUP_NAME=, DFOBJ_CONTR=105708991, DFNUMBER_CONTR=№, от 09.07.2013, DFDATE_BEGIN=09.07.13, DFSUB_NUM=503, DFINVOICE=, DFBALANCE_OUT=0}]
```

Метод `selectedRows.contains()` вернул `true`. Каким образом можно переопределить `equals` и `hashCode` для этой цели?

**UPDATE:**
Класс `Row`:

```
public class Row implements HtmlPainter, Comparable<Row> {

    private String styleName = "editable-grid-row";
    private Map<String,String> rowData;
    private int index;

    public interface RowSelectChangeListener{
        void onSelectChange(Row row);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getRowData() {
        return rowData;
    }

    public void setStyleName(String styleName) {
        this.styleName = styleName;
    }

    RowSelectChangeListener selectListener;

    public void setSelectListener(RowSelectChangeListener selectListener) {
        this.selectListener = selectListener;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public Map<String,TypedValue> asParams(){
        Map<String,TypedValue> params = new FastMap<TypedValue>();
        rowData.forEach((k,v) -> {params.put(k, new TypedValue(v));});
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Row [" + (rowData != null ? "rowData=" + rowData : "") + "]";
    }

    private static String SELECTED = "eg-selected-row";

    private Element el;

    private static final RowTemplates TEMPLATES = GWT.create(RowTemplates.class);

    private Cell[] cells;
    private GridView gridView;

    public Row(int index, Map<String, String> rowData, GridView gridView){
        this.rowData = rowData; 
        this.index = index;
        this.gridView = gridView;
    }

    public HTMLPanel getGridPanel(){
        return gridView.pnl;
    }  

    public void setCells(Cell[] cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    public Cell getCell(int index) {
        return cells[index];
    }

    public String getValue(String key){
        return rowData.get(key);
    }

    public String getId(){
        return rowData.get("DFOBJ");
    }

    public void putValue(String k , String v){
        rowData.put(k , v);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderStartTag(SafeHtmlBuilder builder) {
        builder.append(TEMPLATES.startRowDiv(styleName, index, hashCode()));
    }

    @Override
    public void renderFinishTag(SafeHtmlBuilder builder) {
        builder.append(TEMPLATES.endRowDiv());
    }
}
```

Comment: Класс Row тоже покажите

Comment: Выложил класс Row

Comment: Ну тогда нескромный вопрос.... Откуда , собственно, у вас эти 2 строки вывода берутся , которые якобы объекты типа Row, если у вас в этом классе таких полей не существует, да и toString не переопределен, чтобы это вывести.

Comment: toString() переопредлен, вот он: @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Row [" + (rowData != null ? "rowData=" + rowData : "") + "]";
 }

Comment: Различие получается, только в содержимом вот этой Map: private Map<String,String> rowData;

Comment: Если  у вас приведенные вами обекты являются просто сохраненными строками , т.е. переменными типа String , то ничего вы не переопределите, потому как в таком случае переопределять нужно сам класс String, а он final. Если вы хотите работать с такими данными, создайте соответсвующий класс и распарсивайте эти строки, присваивая соответсвующие хначения переменным класса. А потом уже переопределяйте equals и hashCode своего класса.

Comment: Нет, это не строки, в сэте объекты класса `Row`. Строки, это результат вывода `toString`

Comment: Я вижу, чем типизирован сет. Зато я не вижу в класса роу соотвествующие поля, указанные при выводе.

Comment: В расчет хэшкода включите расчет хэшкода для содержимого `Map`, типа там суммируйте хэши ключей и значений например. А в `equals` соответственно сравнивайте пары, если для всех равных ключей равны их значения, то equals -> true

Comment: iksuy, получается разница лишь в том, что в этой `Map` присутствует элемент `null=T`

Comment: Не пойдет. Мар типизирован стрингами. А стринги приходят, судя по всему, разные. И стрингу никак не прикажешь сравнить только часть строки.

Comment: Дмитрий Александрович, немного не понял, предлагаете создать класс, с полями, которые лежат в мапе?

Comment: @S.Ivanov объясните "null=T" участвет в сравнении? Если да, то объекты не равны, т.к. у второго нет "null=T".

Comment: Виктор, нет, при сравнении не нужно учитывать `null=T`. Должно быть равно все остальное, `null=T` не важно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Виктор, нет, при сравнении не нужно учитывать null=T. Должно быть равно все остальное, null=T не важно.

Тогда как посоветовал iksuy:

> В расчет хэшкода включите расчет хэшкода для содержимого Map, типа там суммируйте хэши ключей и значений например. А в equals соответственно сравнивайте пары, если для всех равных ключей равны их значения, то equals -> true

Хешкод предлагаю такой, он не будет зависеть от количества элементов.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int h = 0;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = rowData.entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> next = i.next();
        if(next.getKey() != null) {
            h += next.hashCode();
        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

---

Equals потестируйте такой, на вид должен работать.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Row row = (Row) o;


        Map<String, String> OrowData = row.rowData;

        //проверим списки ключей

        Set<String> copy = new HashSet<>(OrowData.keySet());
        Set<String> original = new HashSet<>(rowData.keySet());
        copy.remove(null);
        original.remove(null);

        if (!copy.equals(original))
            return false;

        //если все ключи совпадают проверим каждое занчение по ключу

        for (String key : original) {
            if (!rowData.get(key).equals(OrowData.get(key)))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

По задумке должен выдать false если количество ключей или их имя разное (не учитывая null). Если тут все хорошо, то дальше идем по списку ключей без null и проверяем в каждой `Map` их наличие и соответствие. null спецально удалял из копии, вдруг в оригинальной `Map` он вам ещё понадобиться.

Comment: Именно так я и делал. Только все равно, это учитывает `null=T` и объекты соответственно не равны

Comment: Тогда костылем. Сейчас ответ отредактирую

Comment: @S.Ivanov а количетво элементов карты фиксированное или в одной строке может быть 10 записей, в другой 20?

Comment: оно количество различное может быть. Костылем сделал так: rowData.remove(null); в `equals` и `hashCode`. Не знаю, насколько так правильно

Comment: @S.Ivanov поправил код в ответе, попробуйте

Comment: почему-то некорректно отрабатывает `hashCode`. Ваш `equals` совместно с моим `hashcode` работает корректно: public int hashCode() {
  rowData.remove(null);
  return rowData != null ? rowData.hashCode() : 0;
 }

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68379/discussion-between--and-s-ivanov).